# C split a string into individual words and save the individual words in an array

Tags: c, pointers

so let.s say the user types "program one two three".  i save that in the userTyped array and pass it to the parse() function. i need the parse() function to make it so that

userargv[0] is program

userargv[1] is one

userargv[2] is two

etc

i can tell it must be something involving pointers, but i can.t figure it out. code is below:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char userTyped[1000];

char* userargv[100];//this is where i need the parse() function to store the arguments to pass to execv

printf("typesomething>");

fgets(userTyped, 1000, stdin);

parse(userTyped, &userargv);

return 0;
}



int parse(char* userTyped, char* userargv){

const char whitespace[2] = " "; //the deliminator
char *strings;

strings = strtok(userTyped, whitespace);

while( strings != NULL )
{
    strings = strtok(NULL, whitespace);

 }
//THIS ALL WORKS, BUT I NEED TO DO SOMETHING LIKE userargv[i] = strings;
//OR *userargv[i] = &strings;
//OR SOMETHING LIKE THAT.

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The standard library function `strtok` can help you with part of this.

Comment: This feels homeworky.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer  yes, this is homework. but i.m just asking for help with this one syntax problem, not my actual assignment(which is to write a shell).

Comment: Steve gave you good advice.  Look into `strtok`

Comment: An important thing to remember about `strtok()` is that it tears up whatever you give it.  If you need your string for something else, give a copy to `strtok()`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to alloc an array of string (char**), and allocate each of its elements, then copy back in it all found strings;

```
// nb: the function prototype has been slightly modified 
char** parse(char* userTyped, int *nargs){

    const char whitespace[2] = " "; //the deliminator
    char *strings;
    char **arr;
    int n = 0; // initially no element allocated

    strings = strtok(userTyped, whitespace);

    while( strings != NULL )
    {
        if( n ){ // if there are already allocated elements?
            arr = realloc( arr, ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( char** ) );
        }else{
            arr = malloc( ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( char* ) );
        }

        if( !arr ){
            perror( "parse" );
            exit( -1 );
        }

        // duplicate strings
        arr[ n ] = malloc( strlen( strings )+1 ); 

        if( !arr[ n ] ){
            perror( "parse" );
            exit( -2 );
        }
        strcpy(arr[ n ] , strings); // make a copy of the string

        n++;

        strings = strtok(NULL, whitespace);

    }


    // call freeStrArr when done with arr;
    //
    *nargs  = n; // save array size;
    return arr; // return string array
}

// this how to free the returned array;
void freeStrArr(char ** strarr,int n){
    while( n ){
        n--;
        free( strarr[ n ] );
    }
    free( strarr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you think of what you need to get back from your parse function, you know you will want the array of pointers pointing to allocated blocks of memory containing the individual words in `usertyped`, but you will also need to know how many separate words that is. Since you are passing the array of pointers as an argument to be operated on by the function itself, you need only return the number of individual words in the given string. You can use something of the form:

```
int parse (char **words, char *str);
```

(*note:* by passing an *array-of-pointers* (`100`), you are limited to only 100 individual words, without the chance to reallocate if you exceed that number. You can pass a *pointer-to-pointer-to-char** and reallocate if need be. Also note that if you are not returning a negative number as an error condition, the choice of `size_t` for the return may be more appropriate)

When using `strtok`, you can tailor where and how `strtok` separate words by tailoring the *delimiters* `strtok` uses. (e.g. in the sentence `"This. Not that."` if simply breaking on `spaces`, your separated words would include the `'.'` character as well). To prevent that, you can include the `'.'` character in the string of *delimiters* `strtok` uses. From that standpoint, it would also make sense to pass the delimiter list as a parameter to your `parse` function as well:

```
int parse (char **words, char *str, char *delims);
```

You can use an initial call to `strtok` with the original string specified as an argument and then finish parsing the remaining strings in a separate loop passing `NULL` as the argument. Or you can handle both cases in a single `for` loop. It is simply a matter of form, either is fine. An example:

```
int parse (char **words, char *str, char *delims)
{
    int n = 0;
    char *p;

    for (p = strtok (str, delims); p; p = strtok (NULL, delims)) 
    {
        words[n++] = strdup (p);    /* allocate/copy */

        if (n == MAXW) { /* limit reached - realloc/break */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: MAXW reached.\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

A simple example program specifying the delimiters and passing them to the `parse` function along with your array and string could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXW = 100, MAXC = 1000 };

int parse (char **words, char *str, char *delims);

int main (void) {

    char usertyped[MAXC] = {0};
    char *userargv[MAXW] = {NULL};
    char *delims = " \t\n.,:;";
    int i, nwords = 0;

    printf ("typesomething> ");

    if (!fgets (usertyped, 1000, stdin)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(nwords = parse (userargv, usertyped, delims))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: parsed no words.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nwords; i++)
        printf ("userargv[%2d] : %s\n", i, userargv[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < nwords; i++)
        free (userargv[i]);

    return 0;
}

int parse (char **words, char *str, char *delims)
{
    int n = 0;
    char *p;

    for (p = strtok (str, delims); p; p = strtok (NULL, delims)) 
    {
        words[n++] = strdup (p);    /* allocate/copy */

        if (n == MAXW) { /* limit reached - realloc/break */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: MAXW reached.\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strtok_parse
typesomething> a quick brown fox jumps over the laszy dog.
userargv[ 0] : a
userargv[ 1] : quick
userargv[ 2] : brown
userargv[ 3] : fox
userargv[ 4] : jumps
userargv[ 5] : over
userargv[ 6] : the
userargv[ 7] : laszy
userargv[ 8] : dog
```

A couple of extra notes. Generally in C the style avoid the use of *camelCase* variables. Thus `usertyped` instead of `userTyped` above. (another form-only issue). Since `strdup` is allocating memory for you, you should check to insure the return is not `NULL` (just as with `malloc` or `calloc`) to protect against memory exhaustion. Also note you can either `#define SOMECONST value` or as above use an `enum` to define the constants. Let me know if you have further questions.